# Pass XML configuration file to JavaScript via cached HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml, configuration

I need to pass data from an XML configuration file to JavaScript.  The application needs to work entirely offline (I'll be using application cache and localstorage) and I was planning to generate the page using PHP.  Is there an easy way to place the XML in the outputted document in such a way that it will not interfere with standard HTML parsing but still be easily accessible using JavaScript.

Comment: Do you need the XML format after downloading? If not, consider converting to JSON before downloading.

Comment: Would it be easier to encode JSON into the HTML?  Are there other advantages other than decreased bandwidth use?

Comment: If only Javascript needs to access the config info, then use PHP to write the config file in a JSON formatted object in a script tag in the HTML <head>.

Comment: How would I go about parsing that?  Just get the script tag by id and use JSON.parse on the innerHTML?

Comment: It's a data analysis program written for FIRST Robotics.  Every year the game changes, forcing us to rewrite our data analysis application.  This year, I'm attempting to make the program configurable, allowing us to have an XML file that can change the input controls and the output's layout.  The information contained in the file will influence pretty much every function in the entire program.  It will also be used in the PHP to create several database tables.

Comment: So, does this program or the program it works with require an XML formatted input? Here's a JSON to XML Javascript function: http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/

Comment: Another thought, store the XML info as a Javascript string. Then feed the string to whatever needs the XML data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, as suggested by the comments, you can use json instead, then you can set it to an html tags data attribute:

```
<?php $settings = array('name'=>'john');?>
<div id="mydiv" data-settings="<?php echo json_encode($settings); ?>"> <!-- --> </div>
```

Then retrieve it in javascript:

```
var mydiv=document.getElementById('mydiv');
var settings=JSON.parse(mydiv.dataset.settings);
alert(settings.name); //alerts john
```

or simply echo it into a script tag:

```
<script type="javascript">
    var settings=<?php echo json_encode($settings); ?>;
</script>
```